# Mikrotik Routerboard connected to ISP via Cisco 2900 Router

Tags: cisco, mikrotik

I'm sorry it's a bit of a long one and I had to mask some information.

With that said, I am in a conundrum and need help. Our network guy left and I've been tasked with getting the house in order. I do have a bit of background in networking but that's well over a decade ago.

**Key Details:**

About 2,000 workforce mostly connected via omnidirectional & sectoral WLAN

A Cisco 2900 router and a Mikrotik RouterBoard were purchased

DIA via microwave

Connection should be ISP IDU to Cisco Router to Mikrotik RouterBoard to end-users

**ISP given addresses:**

```
IP 1xx.xx.x.162

NM 255.255.255.252

GW 1xx.xx.x.161
```

**ISP given DNS:**

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.1

xxx.xxx.xxx.2
```

**Summarily, I configured the Cisco:**

```
#GE0/0 - 1xx.xx.x.162 255.255.255.252
#GE0/1 - 192.168.xx.1 255.255.255.0

#DHCP pool 192.168.xx.0 255.255.255.0

#Default Route 1xx.xx.x.162

#dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.1 xxx.xxx.xxx.2

#excluded 192.168.xx.241 192.168.xx.254

#GE0/0 nat outside

#GE0/1 nat inside (also source list & overloaded)

#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1xx.xx.x.161
```

It's been a while since I did this but I believe it's ok (corrections will be appreciated if otherwise)

My challenge is Mikrotik.
I've gotten a refresher and I believe setting up hotspot, profiles and users won't be an issue rather IP addressing, DHCP and NAT as there may be a double/conflict with Cisco.

**So, I configured the Mikrotik:**

```
**eth1:** 192.168.xx.1/24 (IP of Cisco GE0/1)

**eth2:** 192.168.1.0/24


**DHCP client:** eth1
```

**Routes:**

```
Destination 0.0.0.0/0
 
Gateway 1xx.xx.x.161 (or should I use IP of GE0/1 i.e., 192.168.xx.1?)


**NAT:**
Source 192.168.1.0/24
```

Destination 0.0.0.0/0, Action Masquerade

**DHCP Server Using DHCP setup:**

```
Int 2

Address 192.168.1.0/24

Gateway 192.168.1.1(IP of Mikrotik)

Address to give out (192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.254)

DNS servers (192,168.1.1, xxx.xxx.xxx.1, xxx,xxx,xxx,2)
```

**NAT:**

```
port-forwarding using netmap on port 80.
```

That's it with Mikrotik and like I said, hotspot, profiles and users won't be an issue But I really need help on the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until somebody actually versed in Mikrotik provides a better answer, I think you could:

- change Mikrotik eth1 to be 192.168.xx.2/24 instead of 192.168.xx.1
- change Mirkotik default route to: Destination 0.0.0.0/0 Gateway 192.168.xx.1 instead of ISP's .161
- add DNAT of port 80 also to Cisco to chain to Mikrotik
- later consider dropping SNAT from Mikrotik and instead add a route on Cisco destination 192.168.1.0/24 gateway 192.168.xx.2 (are there reasons for the SNAT to exist?)

Comment: • In that case I'll change the excluded dhcp in cisco to 192.168.xx.1 - 192.168.xx.10. Then assign 192.168.xx.2 to the Mikrotik eth1

• As for the gateway of the Mikrotik, it should be the IP address of the Cisco GE0/1 192.168.xx.1 not the gateway provided by the ISP. I made a mistake when typing in the info I guess.

• Will do 

• Also a valid point I think. 

Thanks will see how it goes and let you know.